# Конфигурация веб сервера

Tags: ubuntu, веб-сервер, настройка

Ожидаемые нагрузки 30-40 человек, на страницах максимум 2 js скрипта которые постоянно шлют на сервер запросы, 60-80 запросов в секунду точно ожидается  (CRM система самописная), Ubuntu 16.04 (выбрал ее т.к. с ней знаком)

Поставил Apache2, php7.0, mariaDb-server, svftpd, ssh(по умолчанию хостер поставил)

это все дело занимает 200 мб оперативной памяти в простое, это нормально для такой конфигурации?

Второй вопрос, нормальная ли выбрана конфигурация для таких нагрузок?

p.s. первый раз конфигурирую сервер

Comment: загрузку лучше указывать в запросах в секунду (миллисекунду)

Comment: @Mikhail примерно они будут 60-80 запросов в секунду делать будут, js скрипты запрашивают актуальную инфу

Comment: дополните вопрос

Comment: А нафига вам 60-80 запросов в секунду?

Comment: @andreymal Со всяких месседжеров сервер соберает колбеком сообщения, js спрашивает есть ли что-то новое или нет

Comment: @Ghost и почему js спрашивает через запросы, а не через вебсокеты?

Comment: @andreymal 1. Ниразу не делал 2. Нужно запустить еще вчера 3. Предыдущий программист испарился 4. в этой системе всего 15 функций на тучу разных действий без единого комментария и с переменными типа $a $b $c $d и сериализвоанными массивами находящимися в бд

Comment: У апача загрузка памяти сильно зависит от количества воркеров. Количество воркеров зависит от максимального времени обработки запроса, и количества запросов. Грубо говоря - крайне не желательно (не рекомендуется) одному воркеру давать хотя бы два запроса сразу, это может привести к ошибкам в работе некоторых криво написанных скриптов.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Хммм.... команда top показывает 2 процесса apache2, я так понял 1 главный, 2ой воркер....